# c# syntax embading html code

Tags: c#, html

I have a problem with the switch syntax in C#. I am embedding HTML code in my C# program. I have links in .js and .css files, but I need to insert C# code like this "\" character. After I do it, the link will be broken.

code in html:

code in C# :

```
"<script src=\"http://www.amcharts.com/lib/amcharts.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>  "+
```

[Video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=nLBzTN1JO7I&feature=youtu.be) of my problem.

Comment: Please show your code, how can we know what's wrong? You're probably just forgetting to escape the backslash "\\"

Comment: Next time just include a couple of code fragments in your question, that's a lot easier for us and for you...

Comment: you can chceck in video (:

Answer (score 2):

Use a double `\\`, that should escape the characters.

Alternativeley use the Verbatim string literal:

```
var path = @"\folder1\folder2\File.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it, so try it this way `"\\"`.
Or escape it by putting and @ sign before the string `@"\"`

Edit based on the video: I've checked the video. Visual Studio editor interprets the link differently than how it will be present in the compiled code. You can disregard the problem, as the editor thinks the URL is `http://www.amcharts.com/lib/amcharts.js\` and tries to open it, but when you compile the code, it will be OK.

If you would like the editor to open it correctly also, then you should replace the escaped quote marks with apostrophes like this:

```
"<script src='http://www.amcharts.com/lib/amcharts.js' type='text/javascript'></script>"
```

Comment: this <script src=\"\\http://www.amcharts.com/lib/amcharts.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>  but still is it wrong...please correct me if is it bad